# cannot open /etc/shadow message on CentOS 6.10

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

When I try to delete a user or add a user to the `wheel` group I got this message

```
[root@server]# userdel --remove username
userdel: cannot open /etc/shadow
[root@server]#
```

I'm running:

```
[root@server]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `/etc/shadow` exist? What are its permissions?

Answer (score 0):

First, I had to run lsattr /etc/shadow/ to see if the permissions had been changed

I fixed it by running `chattr -a /etc/shadow`
After this, I was able to delete the user

Comment: First, I had to run `lsattr /etc/shadow/` to see if the permissions had been changed.